# how to prevent user to go back to logged in pageusing next button on login page

Tags: asp.net, security, caching, browser

I want to prevent user to use next button to go back to logged in pages after using back button to go to login page.

For eg:

there are two pages login and default

first time user enters his login name and password on login page and go to default page

and then uses browser back button to go to login page

the issue is if user presses next button on login page he is able to go to default page without any authentication.

I want user should again enter username and password.

I have used Response.Cache.SetNoStore to prevent user to go to logged in page after logout.

Comment: What's your question? Did `Response.Cache.SetNoStore` not work? Disabling browser buttons tends to be more annoying than effective (there're endless way to browse back to a password protected page).

Comment: I want if user is on login page he must enter username and password event he logged in previously but come to login page using browser button.

Comment: Have you tried clearing session values in login page Page_load?

Answer (score 0):

In Your login page

- On Page load Clear the Session state. and then proceed your process.
- Restrict the user to click Browser back or Forward button once login page is loaded.
- After this Browser Restriction bring the Focus to Username TextBox. It works
  Check the below URL link hope that help u.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/